# Translating a sentence

Tags: translation

"*I'd rather be a dick than a swallower*"

Pretty straightforward. I tried to solve it by using google translate and what little of Chinese language knowledge I've got but I'm still not sure about it. Do I use the "yǔqí-bùrú" structure, and is it ok to use verb + 者 for swallower?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: （google 中文 I'd rather be a dick than a swallower）
Chinese translation of the whole song New Slaves：http://www.englisher.net/lyrics/lyric/new-slaves/

Comment: @S.Rhee This translation is meaningless.

Comment: To translate poetry, it is not enough to know each word and the grammar.  You must be a poet at least as good as Kanye West, but in both languages.

Comment: meaningless in the sense that 但我宁愿是一个家伙比吞 (But I'd rather be a guy than swallow) may not correctly reproduce "dick" and "swallower"? 
在什么意义上是无意义的？ Anyhow users may wonder whether these words have some kind of hidden pornographic meaning。无论如何，大多数使用者很可能不知道该两个词有什么隐藏淫秽的意义。

Comment: It seems "being a guy" is rather meaningless, but can the same be said about "swallow"? It seems 吞 could imply dominating others as in ～并。～蚀。～占 (applicable to countries, but maybe in poetry it can extend to people). This of course would be opposite to the intended meaning. For the intended meaning one might think of 气忍声吞 （iciba： 解释：受了气而勉强忍耐，不说什么话）。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uh...This sentence is not very polite.

Yes, you can use  the "yǔqí-bùrú"（与其-不如） structure when you use Chinese to state "A than B" at some time. But I think another similar structure is more widely used and maybe more correct for this sentence:"bǐqǐ-gèng"（比起-更）or "yǔqí-gèng"(与其-更).

English: *I'd rather be a dick than a swallower*

Chinese: *"bǐqǐ" to be a swallower, I "gèng" would like to be a dick*

It's ok to use verb + "者" for swallower, but since "dick" shows up after "swallower" in Chinese, you'd better describe "swallower" more clearly like "dick-swallow"+"者".

And since maybe you don't understand the culture difference between English and Chinese. I would like to give you another statements to help you translate this sentence better.

Compared with being a dick-swallower, I would rather to the one whose dick is swallowed by others.

or

Compared with being a man who swallow other's dick, I would rather to be a man who let others swallow his dick.